# Mystery duplicate values

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, update, cursor, loop

I'm using a unique list to populate up to 10 fields for a fc with correct geometry, in an "overloading" manner as you would in excel. I noticed on my first run through I had an "index out of range" error, which was strange as values should not populate more than 10 fields per record. I did a bit of an error check with a "break" and print, and it seems from the final result that there are duplicate values being entered where there most definitely should not be. Problem code:

```
for x in uniqueList:
    query = "[BAND_NUM] = \"%s\"" % x
    if x <> "" and x <> " " and x is not None:
        try:
            gp.MakeFeatureLayer("FIRST", "lyr1")
            gp.MakeFeatureLayer("END", "lyr2")
            gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr1", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
            gp.SelectLayerbyLocation("lyr2", "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN", "lyr1", "", "NEW_SELECTION")

            cursor = gp.UpdateCursor("lyr2")
            urow = cursor.next()
            count = 0
            print x

            # update NULL or blank fields
            while urow:
                # this was my error check
                if count == 10:
                    print count
                    break

                if urow.getValue(fieldvalues[count]) is not None and urow.getValue(fieldvalues[count]) <> "":
                    count += 1
                # go to next feature only after an update
                else:

                    urow.setValue(fieldvalues[count], x)
                    cursor.updateRow(urow)
                    count = 0
                    urow = cursor.Next()


            gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr1","CLEAR_SELECTION")
            gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr2","CLEAR_SELECTION")
        except arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:
            gp.AddError(gp.GetMessages(2))
        finally:
            gp.Delete("lyr1")
            gp.Delete("lyr2")
            del urow, cursor

del gp
```

The list looks like - fieldvalues = ['FN1', 'FN2', 'FN3', 'FN4', 'FN5', 'FN6', 'FN7', 'FN8', 'FN9', 'FN10']

I believe the problem is in the way I'm trying to loop this - my first if statement has no cursor.next() because I want to stay on the same record, at a higher index. The logic is that if the record gets updated, go to the next one in the cursor. I had something similar before where I would append one field in a comma delimited manner, but it appears I won't be using a look-up table so 10 fields is the way I'm going.

Here's an example of the duplication - [image: pic]

Comment: trying an alternative - 
    `while urow:
        for i in fieldvalues:
            if urow.getValue(i) is None or urow.getValue(i) == "":
                urow.setValue(fieldvalues[count], str(u))
                cursor.updateRow(urow)
                urow = cursor.Next()
                break`

Answer (score 1):

Solved with -

```
if str(u) <> "" and str(u) <> " ":
        try:
            gp.MakeFeatureLayer("FN_THEME", "lyr1")
            gp.MakeFeatureLayer("FN_THEME_Final", "lyr2")
            gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr1", "NEW_SELECTION", query1)
            gp.SelectLayerbyLocation("lyr2", "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN", "lyr1", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
            cursor = gp.UpdateCursor("lyr2")
            urow = cursor.Next()
            while urow:
                for i in fieldvalues:
                    if urow.getValue(i) is None or urow.getValue(i) == "":
                        urow.setValue(i, str(u))
                        cursor.updateRow(urow)
                        urow = cursor.Next()
                        break
            gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr1", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
            gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr2", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        except:
            gp.AddError(gp.GetMessages(2))
        finally:
            gp.Delete("lyr1")
            gp.Delete("lyr2")
            del urow, cursor
```

Though Python freezes at the very end.